# Apache Spark Build error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm building Apache spark source code in ubuntu 14.04.4 (spark version: 1.6.0 with Scala code runner version 2.10.4) with command

> sudo sbt/sbt assembly

and getting the following error,

> [warn]   def deleteRecursively(dir: TachyonFile, client: TachyonFS) {
>   
> [warn]                                                   ^
>   
> [error]  
> [error]      while compiling:
>   /home/ashish/spark-apps/spark-1.6.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/random/package.scala
>   
> [error]         during phase: jvm 
> [error]      library
>   version: version 2.10.5 
> [error]     compiler version: version
>   2.10.5 
> [error]   reconstructed args: -deprecation -Xplugin:/home/ashish/.ivy2/cache/org.spark-project/genjavadoc-plugin_2.10.5/jars/genjavadoc-plugin_2.10.5-0.9-spark0.jar
>   -feature -P:genjavadoc:out=/home/ashish/spark-apps/spark-1.6.1/core/target/java -classpath /home/ashish/spark-apps/spark-1.6.1/core/target/scala-2.10/classes:/home/ashish/spark-apps/spark-1.6.1/launcher/target/scala-2.10/classes:/home/ashish/spark-apps/spark-1.6.1/network/common/target/scala-2.10/classes:/home/ashish/spark-apps/spark-1.6.1/network/shuffle/target/scala-2.10/classes:/home/ashish/spark-apps/spark-1.6.1/unsafe/target/scala-2.10/classes:/home/ashish/.ivy2/cache/org.spark-project.spark/unused/jars/unused-1.0.0.jar:/home/ashish/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-14.0.1.jar:/home/ashish/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-all/jars/netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:/home/ashish/.ivy2/cache/org.fusesource.leveldbjni/leveldbjni-all/bundles/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/home/ashish/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/bundles/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar:/home/ashish/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/bundles/jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar:/home/ashish/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/bundles/jackson-......and
>   many other jars...
>
> [error]  
> [error]   last tree to typer:
>   Literal(Constant(collection.mutable.Map)) 
> [error]
>   symbol: null 
> [error]    symbol definition: null 
> [error]
>   tpe: Class(classOf[scala.collection.mutable.Map]) 
> [error]
>   symbol owners:  
> [error]       context owners: package package ->
>   package random 
> [error]  
> [error] == Enclosing template or
>   block == 
> [error]  
> [error] Template( // val :
>    in package random,
>   tree.tpe=org.apache.spark.util.random.package.type 
> [error]
>   "java.lang.Object" // parents 
> [error]   ValDef( 
> [error]
>   private 
> [error]     "_" 
> [error]      
> [error]
>    
> [error]   ) 
> [error]   DefDef( // def ():
>   org.apache.spark.util.random.package.type in package random
>   
> [error]      
> [error]     "" 
> [error]
>   [] 
> [error]     List(Nil) 
> [error]      //
>   tree.tpe=org.apache.spark.util.random.package.type 
> [error]
>   Block( // tree.tpe=Unit 
> [error]       Apply( // def ():
>   Object in class Object, tree.tpe=Object 
> [error]
>   `package`.super."" // def (): Object in class Object,
>   tree.tpe=()Object 
> [error]         Nil 
> [error]       )
>   
> [error]       () 
> [error]     ) 
> [error]   ) 
> [error]
>   ) 
> [error]  
> [error] == Expanded type of tree == 
> [error] 
>   
> [error] ConstantType(value = Constant(collection.mutable.Map))
>   
> [error]  
> [error] uncaught exception during compilation:
>   java.io.IOException 
> [error] File name too long 
> [warn] 45
>   warnings found 
> [error] two errors found 
> [error]
>   (core/compile:compile) Compilation failed 
> [error] Total time:
>   5598 s, completed 5 Apr, 2016 9:06:50 AM

Where I'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should build Spark with Maven...

download the source and run ./bin/mvn clean package

Answer (score -1):

Probably similar to http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/spark-github-source-build-error-td10532.html

Try `sudo sbt/sbt clean assembly`

Comment: it doesn't work for me too, still getting the same error